# Подключение модулей python друг в друга

Tags: python, архитектура, импорт, модули

Пишу игру на pygame. Есть основной класс-одиночка App, в котором просходит основной цикл игры. Когда стал описывать юниты, то пришла в голову идея вынести всю анимацию в отдельный класс => в отдельный файл. Но для отрисовки в классе Animation надо хранить ссылку на объект screen, который находится в классе App, а в классе App надо хранить список юнитов, у которых есть в параметрах объект класса Animation. Отсюда проблема: цикличное подключение модулей (App в Animation, Animation в Unit, Unit в Units, Units в App). Помогите пожалуйста разорвать этот замкнутый круг.

Comment: Ну или хотя бы нормальную структуру классов для решения этой проблемы.

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Помогите пожалуйста!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: В идеале все остальные классы (Animation, Unit, Units и т.д.) не должны знать, что существует класс App, но могут знать о существовании друг друга.

Comment: Разве каждый модуль не должен выполнять свою единственную задачу? Я был уверен, что в каждом файле должен быть один класс, реализующий свою основную задачу. Иначе файлы будут загромождены. А  прописывать класс анимации в основном файле игры я не хочу. И если в иделе Animation не должен знать об App, то где хранить объект окна pygame? А так же переменную clock, на которой завязана отрисовка анимации и смена

Comment: изображений? Я был уверен что в классе App и нужно... А так спасибо. Подумаю на эту тему. Вдруг что получится...

Comment: pygame можно передавать в Animation при создании объекта. То же самое про clock.

Comment: Спасибо. Ответ лежал на поверхности) Сейчас попробую.

Comment: А как вообще подключать модули python друг в друга? Я знаю что это вроде можно, но инфу в инете не нашёл...